# VIm How to fix - Already at oldest change Press ENTER or type command to continue

Tags: vim

I read all the other posts on this problem and tried them all. I am posting this since those solutions did not work for me. I am a vim beginner, so part of the problem here is not understanding all the workings of the .vimrc. Still, I need it to work in order to learn.

I added a line to open Chrome with a shortcut and ever since this I get the above message. I've since deleted the line, which never even worked, as well I've tried all the following which came from other posts, deleting each and trying them in combination.

Adding- 

`set shortmess=a
set cmdheight=2`

Adding- 
`if v:version >= 703
    "undo settings
    set undodir=~/.vim/undofiles
    set undofile
    set undolevels=99999
    set undolevels=10000`
(Point here was to up the undo levels)

Adding- `set nomore`

When I enter into Vim, and then try to exit with `q!`, it always makes me enter the command twice. This never used to happen and must be connected to this error.

On vim 7.4, Sierra, regular terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time I had some weird behaviour like that in Vim, I had something invalid in my `~/.viminfo` file. This file keeps your Vim history: searches, commands, buffers, where you were in files you edited, etc.

My guess is that there are lines in the command line history section that are causing trouble.

To test my theory, rename your `~/.viminfo` to some other name (effectively deleting it to Vim) and see if the behaviour is still there. Should that work and you don't mind losing your Vim history, just delete the file. Otherwise you can try to find the offending lines in it, but be careful to work on a differently named copy because Vim writes to this file.

Comment: This was indeed due to a typo, in the vimrc. It was a pain to find as it was an extra #, but now it is working better and the error described has disappeared.